# Another problem with Arabic font

Tags: discussion, formatting

Well I recently came across this problem. The problem is that Arabic font cannot be put on two separate lines

E.g.
The text was typed like this.

[image]

But it ends up like this.
[image]

Whatever I did the text never went on two separate line. Any solution for this?

Comment: it is not a bug, and it is not restricted to Arabic, and it is not about Arabic font. May I suggest that you edit the post and make it about how to out a line break in the quoted texts? :)

Answer (score 5):

Two spaces at the end of the first line works as well:

> تنیتنیتتنستمننسشمتنبمسیتهتسمهتس [hit space twice]
>   نتبیمبتمهیبتمهیبتهبتهبی

Will be shown like this:

> تنیتنیتتنستمننسشمتنبمسیتهتسمهتس
>   نتبیمبیهتمهیبتمهیبتهبتهبی

Comment: i tried that. the space gets added to the start of the line rather than the end

Comment: @Ashu: It's shown in the same line when you press enter, right? So press space twice at the end of the first line and it'll be shown in a separate line. Press edit link of the answer to see the details.

Answer (score 3):

Try enclosing them in `<pre></pre>` tags. Or use the "*code*" feature instead of *quote* (select a text and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> when you are in the editor)

Or in the *quote* mode itself, Simply put one more extra line in between

> ينتبسمينبسيمنب
>
> مينبمنستيبمنس

Answer (score 2):

As Gigli said the correct way to break the line is to use double space (at the point you want to break the line) like this:

```
>سلامٌ  
>علیکم
```

The result is

> سلامٌ
>   علیکم

Or this:

```
>I break the line  
>here
```

Which gives:

> I break the line
>   here

Answer (score -1):

**Simple fix:**

Instead of doing this:

> >textextxtext
> >textextextext

Place a space in between:

> >textextextextextext
>
> >textextextextextext